# Cannot save any geoprocessing result with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, save

I have a problem to get the code below running as a python script tool in ArcGis 10.2.2. I always get this error Message:
AttributeError: ResultObject: Get attribute save not found
The tool help clearly says that there is a .save function. What am I doing wrong?

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy


# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

inRaster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
DGM = arcpy.Raster(inRaster)

# Process: Fill
Fill_DGM = arcpy.gp.Fill_sa(DGM, "Fill_DGM", "")
Fill_DGM.save("F:/Desktop/test/Filled")
```

Comment: Try arcpy.Raster(dgm)

Comment: I already tried this, just forgot to add it to the code. Still not Working.

Comment: Try replacing gp thing with these 2 lines: from arcpy.sa import *     and Fill_DGM =Fill_sa(DGM)

Comment: I had to replace arcpy.gp.Fill_sa(...) WITH Fill(...) otherwise arcpy doesn't recognize it. After this I get an TypeError: Fill() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given). So I just gave 2 arguments and got these: ExecuteError: ERROR 000875: Output surface raster: Workspace\Fill_dgm11's workspace is an invalid output workspace.
ERROR 000581: Invalid parameters. I really don't get why this isn't working.

Comment: You need 1 parameter, the way I mentioned it in my 2nd comment.

Comment: It's producing the same Errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import * 


# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

inRaster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
DGM = arcpy.Raster(inRaster)

# Process: Fill
Fill_DGM = Fill(DGM)
Fill_DGM.save("d:/scratch/Filled")
```

[image]

Comment: I just started writing a new script and now it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this already has an accepted answer, but for the benefit of other users, here is why your code in its original form failed.

Your code failed because you were calling a **save function** on a [Result object](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm). [Results objects](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm) do not have a save function. They have a **saveToFile function**. This saves information about tool execution, parameters, messages and output. This is not what you intended to do.

This would have sufficed:

```
arcpy.env.workspace  = r"c:\scratch.gdb"
Fill_DGM = arcpy.gp.Fill_sa(DGM, "Fill_DGM", "") #this creates a raster called FILL_DGM in the specified workspace.
```

Things to note:

- The variable Fill_DGM above is a [Result object](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm)
- `Fill_DGM.getoutput(0)` # this returns full path to **FILL_DGM raster**: c:\scratch.gdb\FILL_DGM
- No need for FILL_DGM.save(path_to_disk) # this would fail as explained above.
- [spatial-analyst](/questions/tagged/spatial-analyst) tools accessed via arcpy.sa.**InsertToolNameHere** return [Raster Objects](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/map-algebra/working-with-raster-objects.htm) whereas [spatial-analyst](/questions/tagged/spatial-analyst) tools accessed via arcpy.gp.**insertToolNameHere_sa** return [Result Objects.](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm)
- The type of object returned dictates which functions are available to you.